# Copy long into second half of unsigned char array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, copy, long-integer

I'm new to c++. I need help in storing a long integer value in an unsigned char array of size 128-bits at LSB. For exxample :

```
long int myLong = 12340;
unsigned char  myArray[16] = {};
```

`memcpy(myArray,&myLong,sizeof(long int));` copies it at MSB of the `myArray`,i.e.,

```
0x34300000000000000000000000000000
```

But I need `myLong` to be stored in `myArray` as:

```
0x00000000000000000000000000003430
```

Note: I'm working on a 64-bit little-endian(LSB) machine. And I have to shift the corresponding bytes to right. Is there a way to achieve this objective or any existing function that does this job?

**EDIT:** My bad, I overruled the difference between `myLong = 12340` & `myLong = 0x12340` outputs. I modified the question accordingly & yes, if `myLong = 0x12340` & `memcpy` is used, `myArray` looks like :

```
0x40230100000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with endianess, in fact the result should (with 32-bit `long` and on a MSB machine) be `0x00 0x01 0x23 0x40 0x00 0x00 etc`. I don't know how you get the zero-padding between the digits with `memcpy` of that value. Oh, and if you did this on a LSB machine (like x86 or x86_64) machine the resulting array would be `0x40 0x23 0x01 0x00` followed by all zeroes.

Comment: I'm confused as well. Assuming you're on a PowerPC CPU, why does your output end with `400` instead of `040`? Do you want an extra zero at the end?

Comment: If you want it stored at `array+12`, then just tell it `memcpy(myArray+12,....)`. And, as @JoachimPileborg noted, `0x12340 != 0x01020304`, so your expectations are a bit unclear. On a little-endian machine (i.e. x86 or x86_64), I would have expected your example to produce `0x40230100000...`.

Answer (score 1):

If going by your wanted result, where each nibble (four bits, i.e. each hex-digit) gets its own byte in the resulting array, you could do something like this:

```
size_t i = sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0]);  // Get one beyond last index of array
for (size_t shift = 0; shift < sizeof(myLong) * 8 && i > 0; shift += 4)
    myArray[--i] = static_cast<unsigned char>((myLong >> shift) & 0x0f);
```

See [here for a complete example](http://ideone.com/hRdcnj).